# download and installation guide for windows 10 laptop

Tags: downloads

I am new to Ubuntu and I want to download and install it on my personal laptop, so could you please help me for the same. Is it free or have to pay for it? I am a web developer.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is *free*. You can choose to donate, but it's not a requirement.

You can download Ubuntu for Desktop [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

There are a ton of guides online on how to do a dual boot installation via USB or CD. To be frank, your question in general could be answered by a simple Google search by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to our family Linux (Ubuntu).

You are Little bit aware first.

Ubuntu is an open source software platform that runs everywhere from the smartphone, computer, with micro controller/processor machine.

You can get application/software from launchpad, Debian based applications, and Github.you can get.

```
Windows .exe. offline back.Linux .deb(debian).
```

> You can install application directly.  Check how to [install
>   application in Linux ?](https://www.linux.com/community/blogs/133-general-linux/801474-how-to-install-software-in-linux-an-introduction/) ,  You have lot of offers in Linux.

You have lot of questions. Just search in our askUbuntu, Stack-exchange etc.

> Mind the words .
>   when you are start asking questions you will be grow up...
>   - [E.Ve.Ramasamy.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periyar_E._V._Ramasamy)